# Is there any better documentation or blog post available for integrating Razorpay with Nest and Angular application

Tags: angular8, nestjs, postgresql-10, razorpay

I tried and went through razorpay docs but it always produces following error

```
razorpay_1.Razorpay is not a constructor
```

I am not able to proceed ahead with other things unless I solve this. There is no mention of this error even in Razorpay docs.

Has anyone implemented this gateway before?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you link to the documentation you are using and show what code you have implemented so far? It's kinda hard to say what issue you even could be facing without seeing your code

Comment: @JayMcDoniel The issue is solved. Was using a wrong checkout.js file on angular side. Got the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reffered to official [Razorpay docs](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/) and [this](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-node/blob/master/examples/index.js) link. The integration works seamlessly.